# Laravel 7 footer not displaying in certain webpages

Tags: html, css, laravel, tailwind-css

I created a footer that I wanted to @include to other webpages. As such, I created @section('content'), then at the bottom @include('footer') then @endsection. Now this works only on my contact page which is showing the footer. But is not working on my home or blog pages. Below I will include the code I'm working on Laravel 7, using blade, tailwindcss, html/css. I tried multiple things like moving around @include, or @extends or @yeild but couldn't figure this out. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

When I inspect the homepage, for instance, the footer is being passed through but is mixed in with the navbar. When I inspect the contact page its placed where it should be at the bottom of the page. This has me stumped.

FOOTER

```
@extends('layout')
<footer>
    <div class="flex justify-center bottom-0 bg-gray-800 h-18 pt-4 pb-4 static w-full">

        <a href="https://paolotrulli.com" class="text-white hover:text-blue-800 m-2"><img class="h-10 w-10"
                src="/images/global.svg"></a>

        <a href="https://twitter.com/p_trulli" class="text-white hover:text-lue-800 m-2"><img class="h-10 w-10"
                src="/images/twitter-black.svg"></a>

        <a href="https://github.com/PT-83" class="text-white hover:text-blue-800 m-2"><img class="h-10 w-10"
                src="/images/github.svg"></a>

        <p class="text-white pt-4">Copyright 2020, Paolo Trulli</p>
    </div>
</footer>
@yield('footer')
```

LAYOUT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.0.1/dist/alpine.js" defer></script>
  <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="absolute inset-x-0 top-0">
    <nav x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.window.escape="open = false" class="bg-gray-800">
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="flex items-center h-24">
          <div class="flex items-center">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
              <img class="h-12 w-12" src="/images/startup.svg" alt="icon" />
            </div>
            <div class="hidden md:block">
              <div class="ml-10 flex items-baseline">
                <a href="/home"
                  class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md text-lg font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Home</a>
                <a href="/contact"
                  class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-lg font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Contact</a>
                <a href="/blog"
                  class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-lg font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Blog</a>
                <a href="po"
                  class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-lg font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"></a>
                <a href="#"
                  class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-lg font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
            <button @click="open = !open"
              class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 focus:text-white">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path :class="{'hidden': open, 'inline-flex': !open }" class="inline-flex" stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                <path :class="{'hidden': !open, 'inline-flex': open }" class="hidden" stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div :class="{'block': open, 'hidden': !open}" class="hidden md:hidden">
        <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 sm:px-3">
          <a href="/home"
            class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Home</a>
          <a href="/contact"
            class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Contact</a>
          <a href="/blog"
            class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700">Blog</a>
          <a href="#"
            class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"></a>
          <a href="#"
            class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-4 pb-3 border-t border-gray-700">
          <div class="flex items-center px-5">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
              <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="/images/0.jpeg" alt="My Picture" />
            </div>
            <div class="ml-3">
              <div class="text-base font-medium leading-none text-white">Paolo Trulli</div>
              <div class="mt-1 text-sm font-medium leading-none text-gray-400">paolo.g.trulli@gmail.com</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    @yield('content')

</body>

</html>
```

CONTACT PAGE

```
@extends('layout')
@section('title', 'Contact')

@section('content')

<div class="bg-gray-700 text-center text-lg full-screen pt-6">
    <h1 class="pb-8 text-white text-xl">Contact</h1>
    <form action="/contact" method="POST">
        <div class="justify-center relative">
            <label>
                <input class="border-2 border-gray-800 border-black h-10 w-1/4" type='text' placeholder="Name"
                    autocomplete="off">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="justify-center pt-4">
            <label>
                <input class="border-2 border-gray-800 h-10 w-1/4" type="text" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="justify-center pt-4">
            <label>
                <input class="border-2 border-gray-800 h-20 w-1/4" type="text" placeholder="Type Text Here"
                    autocomplete="off">
            </label>
        </div>
        @csrf
        <div class="text-center pt-6">
            <button
                class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border border-blue-700 rounded justify-center">
                Submit</button>
            <h3 class="pt-6 text-white">I will not SPAM you and your data is Safe!</h3>
            <div class="bg-cover content-center flex justify-center min-h-50">
                <img src="/images/contact.svg" alt="background image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    @include('footer')
    @endsection
```

HOME PAGE

```
@extends('layout')

@section('title', 'Home')
@section('content')

<main>
    <div class="bg-gray-700 text-center text-gray-200 tracking-wider leading-loose h-full">
        <h1 class="pt-6 pb-6 text-lg font-semibold">
            A Website Built and Designed By Me!
        </h1>
        <img class="container-sm mx-auto border-2 border-gray-800" src="/images/0.jpeg">
        <p class="pt-6 text-base capitalize font-semibold">
            Who am I you ask?
        </p>
        <div class="inline-flex">
            <p class="flex-1"></p>
            <p class="flex-1 text-center pt-3 text-justify">
                I am a father of two, a husband of one, and someone who loves to build things. I tend to find
                something I enjoy
                get obsessed with it, and ditch if for something new. Rinsing and Repeating the process. My latest
                obsession, in
                case you didn't notice, creating this website by programming it myself. I have been diving deep into the
                world
                of coding, although it takes time to learn, and the many frustrating issues along the way, I can say for
                certain
                I love to learn and build.
            </p>
            <p class="flex-1"></p>
        </div>
        <p class="text-center pt-6 capitalize font-semibold">
            So what will this site be or provide?</p>
        <div class="inline-flex pt-3">
            <p class="flex-1"></p>
            <p class="flex-1 text-justify">
                I plan to <a href="/blog" target="blank" class="text-teal-500">blog</a> about
                various topics that interest me. Topics will be random, interesting, and makes me curious. Also, I will
                use
                this site to showcase a portfolio of work I complete, beginning with this website and adding projects as
                I
                go.
            </p>
            <p class="flex-1"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</main>

@include('footer')
@endsection
```

Lastly BLOG PAGE

```
@extends('layout')
@section('title', 'Blog')

@section('content')

<main>
    <div class="bg-gray-700 text-center text-gray-700 h-screen text-lg">
        <h3 class='text-gray-300 pt-6 text capitalize'>A place where I create posts on random things that interest me
        </h3>
        <div class="pt-6">
            <form action="/blog" method="post">
        </div>
        <label class=""></label>
        <input type="text" name="title" autocomplete="off">
        @csrf
        <div class="text-center pt-6">
            <button
                class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border border-blue-700 rounded justify-center">
                Add Blog Post</button>
        </div>
        </form>
        <p style="color: red">@error('title') {{ $message }} @enderror</p>
        <ul>
            @forelse ($blogs as $blog)
            <li>{{ $blog->title }}</li>
            @empty
            <li>
                <h3 class="text-center pt-4 text-red-500">No Blog Posts Yet</h3>
            </li>
            @endforelse
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</main>

@include('footer')
@endsection
```

Comment: Your footer does not need `@extends('layout')` or `@yield('footer')`. If you `@extend` a layout anything outside of `@section`s will not be rendered.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the `@extend` and `@yield` in the footer page. However, the issue still remains the same.

Comment: Make sure you have proper HTML in your pages, your layout for example is missing closing tags, it starts with a `<div>` but ends with `<nav>`? Use a proper IDE and autoformat/use proper indentation, same with your contact page, starts with a `<div>`, ends with `</form>`, your homepage has two closing `</div>`s. That's most likely why your footer is screwed

Comment: In fact, your footer file seems to be the only one without HTML errors. `<div class="pt-6"><form action="/blog" method="post"></div>` Don't close the `<div>` here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, improper html tags. Lesson learned to ensure open and close tags are equal. Because I was short `</div>` tags my code was suffering and not working as it should. 
Credit goes to @kerbholz

Comment: Wow. This one got me totally stumped. Was missing a closing </table> tag. Sometimes even Php Storm misses it!